# send value of a text field with dynamic id as parameters to a link_to_remote url in rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my application i need to add sibling details i used nested form gem that generates dynamic ids to text fields . When i clck on go i need to send the value in admission_no text field to get validated. Is there any way to get the value of this field and send as params.

```
     <%= f.simple_fields_for :siblings,@student.siblings do |sibling| %>                      
           <%= sibling.label :admission_no %>
           <%= sibling.text_field :admission_no ,:class=>"form-control "%>
           <span class="input-group-btn">
           <%= link_to "Go!", students_admissioncheck_path,:id => "button_go",:remote => true, :class  => "btn btn-default" %>
           </span>

    <% end %>
```

the source of the field i need value from is generated as follows

```
<input class="form-control " id="student_siblings_attributes_1395484643958_admission_no" name="student[siblings_attributes][1395484643958][admission_no]" type="text">
```

when i press go button my url must be like /students/admissioncheck?val="value in text field"
how can i retrieve the value from the text field since its id is dynamic

Comment: What are you asking? Can you cut the question down to remove any stuff that doesn't pertain to it directly?

Comment: is their a way to send value in textfield as params to a url . the id of the text field is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you're using the `child_index: Time.now.to_i` method or something

I would do use manual Ajax & refactor if it works:

```
 <%= f.simple_fields_for :siblings,@student.siblings do |sibling| %>                      
         <%= sibling.label :admission_no %>
         <%= sibling.text_field :admission_no ,:class=>"form-control "%>
         <span class="input-group-btn">
             <%= link_to "Go!", students_admissioncheck_path, id: "button_go", class: "btn btn-default" %>
         </span>
 <% end %> 

 #app/assets/javascripts/application.js
 $("#button_go").on("click", function() {
     $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        data: $(this).parents("form").find("input.form_control").val().serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            //something here
        }
     });
 });
```

Although this is pretty sketchy, and I mainly posted because you don't have any answers yet!